Proper database design when 1 entity can belong to 2 possible others
I am making a database design for a questionnaire type application that allows admins to build a form up and create questions of different types. As basic form can consist of many sections, sections have many pages, and the pages then have many questions.
The basic schema that I currently have is as follows:
Form > (has many) > Sections > (has many) > Pages > (has many) > Questions
The questions table, has a page_id which is a FK to the pages.id column. I also have different question sub type tables that house information for specific types of question, such as a select dropdown box or radio buttons. But I've left those out for simplicity.
This schema worked perfectly for my questionnaire application until I was tasked with implementing a 'repeater' type question, where other questions are essentially nested inside the repeater, and then repeated as many times as the user requires. For example if there was a form where the user needed to fill out the names of their siblings, a repeater could be used that repeats a 'name' field the user can fill in, and enter as many sibling names as they require.
So the solution I came up with was to use a polymorphic design on the questions table, that allows the question to belong to either a page, or a repeater question. This involved removing the page_id column and adding instead a questionable_type, and questionable_id. The type would be EITHER Page or Question(repeater), and the ID would then relate to a record of either of those types. One drawback to this is that you can't use foreign keys.
I should mention that I am using PHP Laravel for this application, which is why I initially reached for polymorphic relation as Laravel makes it extremely easy. However since then I have read up on why a polymorphic relation might not be the most efficient or best design, and have done some reading up on supertype/subtype design. Such as the following question on here which was helpful: Polymorphic relationships vs separate tables per type
So my question is how would I implement supertype/subtype for this particular schema, in that a question can either belong to a page, or a repeater, or is there a better way to solve this problem. I can see a few different solutions that I have tried to outline below.
Solution 1 - Separate page_questions and repeater_questions tables
This would probably simplify things, but it would lead to duplicate columns in each table where certain data would be shared (label, type etc.) One problem I can forsee is when I need to start storing user answers, I'd have to store an answer against either a page_question or a repeater_question, which just moves my problem to another table.

I have left some columns out of the questions tables for simplicity, there will be more duplicates than just label.
Solution 2 - One question table with two pivot tables, page_question and repeater_question
This seems like a nice solution, although it would complicate the logic in the application to create the questions and assign them to either a page or repeater, but nothing that would be too annoying. This would also mean that there could be a record in the questions table that isn't linked to either a page or repeater, which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Solution 3 - One supertype with subtypes of Page or Repeater
This is where I'm confusing myself, I initially thought the Question would be the supertype, and the repeater / page question would be the subtype. But that is incorrect and wouldn't solve my problem unless the FK to the page or repeater were on the subtypes table, which is essentially the same as solution 2 at that point.
One problem I can see is that page and repeater don't actually feel like the same 'supertype', I wouldn't even know where to begin with naming the supertype, 'Questionable'? This seems strange but it would allow the questions table to have a FK to a questionable_id, which would then have a relation to either of the subtypes.
I hope all that makes sense,
Thanks very much in advance, any insight is greatly appreciated!
